# Query regarding UpgradeableApp API for migration of google apps marketplace v1 to v2

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have app using oauth 1.0 in old marketplace which is installed on 300 domains . We are in process of migrating to oauth 2.0 for new marketplace. We are using UpgradeableApp API to do migration for existing domains. I am following steps specified in :
https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2
While testing for a test domain I have Linked the two apps by entering the Chrome Web Store item ID of the new app into the dashboard of the old app.

Now when I try to install application from old marketplace, it still installs new application from new marketplace. "Add it now" button is now replaced with "Install app" button.

I have removed the new web store item id from app listing. but still it istalls app with new item id.

How can I remove this association. I want clients to install my oauth 1.0 app and not the new app (oauth 2.0) for some more days atleast.

Comment: There was a warning in the UI that said the CWS listing cannot be un-associated. Sorry there is no way to go back now.

Comment: that's a fairly critical bit of info not mentioned in the docs!